# Found 2 elements with non-unique id. Loading the selected div only to avoid conflict

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have an option select tag where a user picks the option they want on a drop down.

```
<div class="button dropdown"> 
  <select id="languageselector">
     <option value="english">English</option>
     <option value="swahili">Swahili</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I have noted since I am reusing the same ids, it's failing and giving warnings `[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id`. The first option loads well but the second option fails to load correctly giving `[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id`.

Is there a way to disable one based on the selection because I think both are loading the same time hence the conflict?

```
<div class="button dropdown"> 
  <select id="languageselector">
     <option value="english">English</option>
     <option value="swahili">Swahili</option>
  </select>
</div>

 <div id="english" class="language english">
        <form id="reviewForm" method="POST" action="/review/post">
        <div id="reviewFormPage">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('business_name', $provider->businessId, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'businessId']) !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('acceptTerms', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'acceptTerms']) !!}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                        <label>
                        {!! Form::checkbox('existing_customer', '1', false, ['id' => 'existing_customer_review']) !!}
                            I am an existing customer.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </form>
 </div>


 <div id="swahili" class="language swahili">
        <form id="reviewForm" method="POST" action="/review/post">
        <div id="reviewFormPage">
        {!! csrf_field() !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('business_name', $provider->businessId, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'businessId']) !!}
        {!! Form::hidden('acceptTerms', null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'acceptTerms']) !!}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="checkbox icheck">
                        <label>
                        {!! Form::checkbox('existing_customer', '1', false, ['id' => 'existing_customer_review']) !!}
                            Mimi ni mteja anayerudi.
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </form>
 </div>
```

The JavaScript code is as below;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#languageselector').change(function(){
        $('.language').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Not clear from what is shown where you are duplicating ID's. Provide an html only representation of the problem (without server side code) as per [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl That would be `#reviewFormPage` and `#reviewForm` as far as I can see

Comment: @charlietfl I mean like I am getting `DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #businessId` .... The two selection div have exactly same form with exactly same fields but different labels.

Comment: Use class instead then

Comment: @User101 I agree with charlie, is there a specific reason why you need to use id instead of class in this case?

Comment: @LinusJuhlin the errors are on the form fields eg the text fields..... I guess the two selection options load. Question is can you disable loading one until when selected to avoid the conflict?

Comment: @charlietfl where exactly?

Comment: @User101 it feels like you're making this unnecessarily complicated for yourself. Are you unable to use a class instead of an ID in this case?

Comment: @LinusJuhlin could you point out where I could use this?

Comment: `{!! Form::hidden('business_name', $provider->businessId, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => 'businessId']) !!}` Change `'id' => 'businessId'` to `'class' => 'businessId'`

Answer (score 1):

**If you don't have a reason for using an ID**, then as per my comment, I suggest you change your ID's into classes.

In

`{!! Form::hidden('business_name', $provider->businessId, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id' => '']) !!}`

Remove `'id' => 'businessId'` and add `'businessId'` to the `class` key.

Comment: needs to be combined with the existing class

Comment: Mmh... The id is the unique identity in this case... I need it

Comment: Well, okay, you're basically explaining what id is in HTML, but you haven't made it clear why it is needed in your app.